# Obtener la cantidad de array tipo json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, jsonarray

Necesito recorrer N arreglos de tipo json con la librería jquery ademas estos de deben ir llenando dentro de un input que esta en una tabla,alguien tiene alguna idea de como lo puedo mi codigo actual funciona perfectamente solo si se retorna un solo arreglo.

Codigo HTML

```
                   <div class="contenido">
                        <h3>Detalle</h3>
                        <form id="detalle-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal style-form" >
                            <input id="n-mesa" name="n-mesa"  type="text"></th>
                           <input type="hidden" id="pos"  name="pos">
                          <table class="table table-fixed" id="pedido">
                          <thead>
                             <tr>
                             <th class="col-xs-2">Codigo</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-2">Qty</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-2">Descripción</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-3">Peso</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-3">Precio</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                            <tr id="fila0">
                                <td class="col-xs-2">
                                         <div class="input-group"><input id="cod0" name="cod0" class="form-control sinborde input-md" placeholder="Ingresar codigo" type="text"></div>
                                 </td>
                                <td class="col-xs-2" ><input id="qty0" name="qty0" class="form-control  sinborde input-sm" type="text"></td>
                                 <td class="col-xs-2" id="producto0"></td>
                                 <td class="col-xs-3">
                                         <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">Kg</div><input id="peso0" class="form-control input-md " name="peso0"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="col-xs-3">
                                         <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="precio0" name="precio0" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tfoot>
                             </table>
                             <table class="table">
                             <tr >
                              <td  class="col-xs-3"></td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3"></td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">Total :</td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">
                                     <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="total" name="total" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td  class="col-xs-3"><button title="Guardar registro" id="save" name="save" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-success "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></button>
                              </td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3"></td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">Propina Sugerida 10% </td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">
                                     <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="propina" name="propina" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                  </form>

                  <?php if (isset($_POST['save'])){
                            save_pedido();
                        }
                  ?>

                 </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Codigo Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//selecciona mesas
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-mesas").change(function () {
            $("#btn-mesas option:selected").each(function () {
                id_mesa = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                     type:"GET",
                     url:"lib/pedidos/select_mesa.php",
                     data:{id_mesa: id_mesa},
                     dataType:"json",
                     success: function(res){
                          // proble esto pero no se me ocurrio ninguna idea para iterar los td de la tabla 
                         while(res){
                            $('#n-mesa').val(res.idmesa);
                            $('#cod'+cod).val(res.idprod);
                            idcod ++;
                            var $cant = $('#qty'+idqty).val(res.qty);
                            idqty ++;
                            $('#producto'+idprod).text(res.producto);
                            idprod ++;
                            $('#precio'+idpre).val(res.precio);
                            idpre ++;

                            idpes ++;
                         }
                            calcular_valores(res.qty,res.precio);
                     },error:function(res){
                            alert("[AJAX] Error: capturando el arreglo!!");  
                     }
                });
            });
        });

 //Carga los productos al formulario

    //declaracion de variables
    var td = 0;
    var qty = 0;
    var producto = 0;
    var peso = 0;
    var precio = 0;
    var idqty =0
    var idprod=0;
    var idpes=0;
    var idpre=0;
    var pos=0;
    var cod =0;
    var idcod =0;

    //Funcion se activa al ingresar el codigo  <br>
    //Funciona solo con el primer td falta iterar 
    $("#pedido tr").find('td:eq(0) input').each(function() {
        $("#pedido tr").find('td:eq(0) input').change(function(){
          cod = $(this).val();

          if(isNaN(cod)){
              alert("El codigo no puede contener letras");

          }else{
                if(id_mesa == null){
                    alert("Es necesario que seleccione una mesa");
                    $('#btn-mesas').focus();
                 }else{
                         $.ajax({
                         type:"GET",
                         url:"lib/pedidos/select_producto.php",
                         data:{id_prod:cod},
                         dataType:"json",
                         success: function(data){
                                var cant = prompt("Ingresar Cantidad:");
                                if(cant>0){
                                    $('#cod'+cod).val(data.ID);
                                    cod++;
                                    var $cant = $('#qty'+idqty).val(cant);
                                    idqty ++;
                                    $('#producto'+idprod).text(data.DESC);
                                    idprod ++;
                                    $('#precio'+idpre).val(data.PRECIO);
                                    idpre ++;
                                    idpes ++;
                                    agrega_fila();
                                    calcular_valores(cant,data.PRECIO);


                                }else{
                                    alert ("La cantidad debe ser mayor a 0");
                                }
                         },error:function(res){
                                alert("[AJAX] Error: capturando el arreglo!! ");     
                         }
                    });
                 }
          }


 });
    });

    //funcion de actiba al hacer clic en el boton
    $("#selec-prod button").click(function(){
              id_prod = $(this).val();
              id_mesa = $("#btn-mesas option:selected").val();

             if(id_mesa == null){

                alert("Es necesario que seleccione una mesa");
                $('#btn-mesas').focus();
             }else{
                     $.ajax({
                     type:"GET",
                     url:"lib/pedidos/select_producto.php",
                     data:{id_prod:id_prod,id_mesa:id_mesa},
                     dataType:"json",
                     success: function(data){
                            var cant = prompt("Ingresar Cantidad:");

                            if(cant>0){
                                $('#cod'+cod).val(data.ID);
                                idcod ++;
                                var $cant = $('#qty'+idqty).val(cant);
                                idqty ++;
                                $('#producto'+idprod).text(data.DESC);
                                idprod ++;
                                $('#precio'+idpre).val(data.PRECIO);
                                idpre ++;

                                idpes ++;

                                    agrega_fila();
                                    $('#pos').val(pos);
                                    calcular_valores(cant,data.PRECIO);

                            }else{
                                alert ("La cantidad debe ser mayor a 0");
                            }
                     },error:function(res){
                            alert("[AJAX] Error: capturando el arreglo!! ");     
                     }
                });
             }

     });

        function agrega_fila(){

        qty ++;
        td ++;
        producto ++;
        peso ++;
        precio ++;
        cod ++;
        fila = '<tr id="fila'+td+'" ><td class="col-xs-2"><div class="input-group"><input placeholder="Ingresar codigo" name="cod'+cod+'" id="cod'+cod+'" class="sinborde form-control input-md"  type="text"></div></td><td class="col-xs-2" ><input id="qty'+qty+'" name="qty'+qty+'" class="form-control  sinborde input-sm" type="text"></td><td class="col-xs-2" id="producto'+producto+'" name="producto'+producto+'"></td><td class="col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">Kg</div><input id="peso'+peso+'" name="peso'+peso+'" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="Fila '+td+'"></div></td><td class="col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="precio'+precio+'" name="precio'+precio+'" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div></td></tr>';
        $('#fila'+pos).after(fila);
        pos++;

     return pos;
     }

     var total = 0;
     var sugerida = 0;
     var subTotal =0;
     var porcentaje = 0.10;


     function calcular_valores(cantidad,precio){
        //calcula el total de la boleta
        subTotal = cantidad * precio;
        total = subTotal + total;
        $('#total').val(total);
        //calcula la propina sugeria
        sugerida = total * porcentaje;
        $('#propina').val(sugerida);
     }

});


</script>
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo por ajax necesito llenar el formulario

`{"idmesa":"2","codventas":"2","codusr":"193178685","estadob":"0","producto":"Leche asada","precio":"1500","idprod":"1","qty":"1"}`

`{"idmesa":"2","codventas":"2","codusr":"193178685","estadob":"0","producto":"Coca-cola","precio":"1000","idprod":"2","qty":"2"}`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear como contenedores de tus inputs, concatenarlos a una variable(por cada tipo de input) y después hacer un append donde quieras que se muestren esos inputs.
Y sería mejor iterar con un `forEach`.

Algo similar a esto:

```
var inputsIdMesas = '';
var inputsX = '';

res.forEach(function (item) {
    inputsIdMesas += '<input id="n-mesa" name="n-mesa"  type="text" value="' + res.idmesa + '"></th>';
    inputsX += '<input id="n-mesa" name="n-mesa"  type="text" value="' + res.idmesa + '"></th>';
});

$('#form').append(inputsIdMesas);
$('#x').append(inputsX);
```